# SKLabelNode error , crash only iOS7

Tags: ios7, swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

I start my project crashes immediately on ios7 , with the following error , but I can not understand how to solve .

```
2014-12-08 18:29:07.605 MyProject[1293:613] +[SKLabelNode nodeWithFileNamed:]:    unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10c6273a0
2014-12-08 18:29:07.608 MyProject[1293:613] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[SKLabelNode nodeWithFileNamed:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10c6273a0'
```

Comment: [SKLabelNode](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/index.html)

Comment: SourceCode would be useful

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in the image bellow the method nodeWithFileNamed: is available in iOS 8.0 and above, this is why your app is crashing on a lower iOS version.

[image: SKNode Class Reference]

Comment: In my code is not present nodeWithFileNamed, i have check the code.. Is not present.

Comment: I guess then you used another method available in iOS 8.0 and above that's using nodeWithFileNamed. Would be really great if you could provide any code that you suspect in causing this error.